# Python3 Regex: Remove all characters except / and | from string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am writing a program in Python3, and I have a string in a variable. This string contains lots of `|` and `/` characters, as well as possible alphanumeric characters and whitespace.

I need a regular expression to get rid of all characters except `|` and `/`, and replace them with nothing.

So basically, `/|||/ blah /|||||/ foo /|/ bar /|||/` would become `/|||//|||||//|//|||/`.

Can anyone help me do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: And may we know what exactly prevents you from writing it down?

Comment: @Ingo Writing what down?

Comment: The regex you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
a = '/|||/ blah /|||||/ foo /|/ bar /|||/'
print(re.sub('[^/|\|]', '', a))

>>> /|||//|||||//|//|||/
```

Comment: Why not just `[^/|]` ?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Though | was always a special character. It may work but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is except in the context of [...] which assumes every character is "OR" the next character

Answer (score 3):

The above one can also be shortened as `re.sub('[^/|]')`, ie without needing to escape the two chars.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex for this. http://regexr.com/ is a great tool to write your own,  but I did it for you below.

```
import re                                       #import regex module

str = '/|||/ blah /|||||/ foo /|/ bar /|||/'
str = re.sub(r"[^|/]", "", str)                 #replaces everything that is not | or /

print(str)
```